# How to add Date Picker in JSP

Tags: jsp

In this JSP, How do I add the Date picker to:

```
<div>
    <label for="surveyStartDate">Survey Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="surveyStartDate" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="surveyEndDate">Survey End Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="surveyEndDate" value="">
</div>  

<div>
    <label for="eventDate">Event Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventDate" value="">
</div>
```

Here is a bit of the code to see where it falls to choose the date picker. Where are some good sites that I can look at to pick the date picker? I just wanted to get fancy and make it easy to pick dates

```
<!-- FORM VALIDATION -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Value of 'btn' set via onclick on submit/clear buttons at end of form
    var btn = "";

    function validate(myform) {
        if (btn == "submit") {
            //Validate Form only on 'submit' button (not for 'clear' button)
            var num = 0;
            var message = "";
            if(myform.name.value == "") {
                message += "- Group Name must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            } 
            if(myform.highschool.value == "") {
                message += "- High School must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }
            if(myform.teacher.value == "") {
                message += "- Teacher must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }
            if(myform.classPeriod.value == "") {
                message += "- Period must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }   
            if(myform.surveyStartDate.value == "") {
                message += "- Survey Start Date must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }
            if(myform.surveyEndDate.value == "") {
                message += "- Survey End Date must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }
            if(myform.eventDate.value == "") {
                message += "- Event Date must be completed \n";
                num = 1;
            }

            if (num == 1) { 
                alert ("Please complete or correct the following required fields: \n\n"+message);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            } //end if
        } //end button if
    } //end func
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<!--HEADER-->
<div id="header">

<img id="logoImg" src="images/cislogo.png" width="200" height="150" alt="Communities In Schools Logo">


<!--Header Text-->
<img id="headerText" src="images/realityuhead.png" width="600" height="80" alt="Reality University Program">
<!--REALITY U LOGO-->
<img id="logoImnewGrp" src="images/realityulogo.png" width="100" height="95" alt="Reality U Logo">

<!--NAVIGATION-->
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>   
    <li><a href="adminhome.jsp">Admin Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="newgroup.jsp">New Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="opengroup.jsp">Open Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="occupations.jsp">Edit Occupations</a></li>
    <li><a href="helpadmin.html">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--END NAVIGATION-->


</div><!--END HEADER-->




<!--MAIN CONTENT CONTAINER -->
<div id="main">

<br><br>

<fieldset>
<h3>Admininstration - Add New Group</h3>
</fieldset>



<br><br>

<div id="mainArea">

<!--START FORM-->
<form id="newGroupForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/RealityUWeb/NewGroupServlet" onSubmit="return validate(this);">

<fieldset>
<br><br>

<% 
//If form never been filled in yet, all values are blank
if (session.getAttribute("newGrp") == null) {
%>

    <div>
        <label for="name">Group Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="highschool">High School:</label>
        <input type="text" name="highschool" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="teacher">Teacher:</label>
        <input type="text" name="teacher" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="classPeriod">Period:</label>
        <input type="text" name="classPeriod" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="surveyStartDate">Survey Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surveyStartDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="surveyEndDate">Survey End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surveyEndDate" value="">
    </div>  

    <div>
        <label for="eventDate">Event Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="studentAccessCode">Student Access Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="studentAccessCode" value="(Auto-Generated after Submit)" readonly>
    </div>
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with JSP. Its just a plain HTML/Javascript issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a date picker to a JSP page is not specifically connected to JSP. You may do this as doing with plain HTML markup.

To add a date picker, you have to choose a good Javascript date picker. As far as I know [JqueryUI date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is good. Here is another [demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/datepicker/) with Jquery Mobile.